# What is preferable to put authentication rules, in the site web config or in a web config file specific to each folder?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, authorization

I have a site with a number of pages in different folders. The pages should be available to users according to their roles. This is defined by rules defined in the authorization tags in the web config file. Where is it preferable to place the different authorization rules, all of them in the site web config file or in web config files specific to each folder?

Is there a difference in performance efficiency or is there any accepted practice?

Answer (score 0):

I found this article [10 Things ASP.NET Developers Should Know About Web.config Inheritance and Overrides](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides) helpful.

Especially this relates to the issue:

> Tip 4: Location, location
>
> > While it's nice to be able to override settings in a subfolder using
> >     nested Web.config files, that can become hard to manage. In a large
> >     application, it can be difficult to manage settings because you can't
> >     see the effective permissions in one place. Another option is to use
> >     the `<location>` element to target settings to a specific location.

There can be differences for management but it seems that there are no differences in performance.